# Show that if $a_n \to 0$ then ($e^{a_n}-1)/a_n \to 1$ for $n \to \infty$

Tags: limits

Can i assume, that $a_n = \frac{1}{n}$ , because $\frac{1}{n} \to 0$ for $n \to \infty$?

If not please show me how to do that, because that's my only idea.

Comment: Check your parentheses... As it currently stands, the limit doesn't actually go to 1.

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is similar to show that
$$\lim_{x\to0}\frac{e^x-1}{x}=1$$
which we can proved it by several methods: the derivative definition, the L'Hôpital's rule or the Taylor series.

Answer (score 1):

So as $n \rightarrow \infty \Rightarrow \dfrac{1}{n} \rightarrow 0$

We'll replace $\dfrac{1}{n}$ with $h$ for simplicity's sake.

You can apply L'Hopital's rule as $\lim\limits_{h \rightarrow 0} e^h - 1 = 0$ and $\lim\limits_{h \rightarrow 0} h = 0$

So $\lim\limits_{h \rightarrow 0}\dfrac{e^h - 1}{h} = \lim\limits_{h \rightarrow 0}\dfrac{\frac{d}{dx}(e^h - 1)}{\frac{d}{dx}(h)} = \lim\limits_{h \rightarrow 0} e^h = 1$